# Uncheck checkbox when certain values(php) from drop down is chosen

Tags: javascript, php, html

i need to uncheck a checkbox when a value is chosen from multi dropdown. The problem is the value is a php value which is generate from foreach.

below is the code of the javascript

```
$("#multi_search_filter").on('change', function () {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val === <?php"'.$row['batch_name'].'" ?>) {
     $('#checkUncheckAll').prop('checked', false);
     return;
  }
  $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', true);
});
```

this is the code of the PHP and HTML

```
<select name="multi_search_filter" id="multi_search_filter" multiple class="form-control selectpicker">
<?php
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
    echo '<option value="'.$row["batch_id"].'">'.$row["batch_name"].'</option>';
  }
?>
</select>
```

this is the input checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkUncheckAll">
```

I tried to search for solution but failed to do so. Appreciate any help

Comment: *when a value is chosen from multi dropdown* Which value?

Comment: Btw I can't understand your logic here that how did you put `$row['batch_name']` inside jquery code

Comment: $row['batch_name'] will not match, you need to set there a value

Comment: change `batch_name` to `batch_id`

Comment: the value is from   echo '<option value="'.$row["batch_id"].'">'.$row["batch_name"].'</option>';

Comment: when i choose this value it will remove the checkbox that is checked.. but i dont know how because its php

Comment: you cant use value which is generated from foreach